# component.scss inside component folder does not work

Tags: angular, sass

When I put styles code in `component.scss`, but it does not affect the referred target, however when I put style code on `src/scss/style.scss` it works perfectly. Does anyone know what is the problem?

If it is lack of technical knowledge, please reference me some material to study.

Comment: Please read this article, there are many solution on there (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the component, watch out what is given as the StyleUrl:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  templateUrl: './something.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./something.component.scss']
})
```

Maybe your syntax is bad, or you are referring to a simple `something.component.**css**` instead of `.scss` file.

Comment: You are right. The angular cli does not created the styleUrls in `@Component` decorator. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this! Sometimes the easy is to easy :-)

Answer (score 54):

If you try to style inside child components it will not work. You should use ng-deep in scss. [More information about styling](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-advanced-styling-guide-v4-f0765616e635).

```
::ng-deep .className {}
```

Comment: I had to wade through ~6 useless threads before finding your answer.

Comment: `::ng-deep` is being deprecated: [link](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: @xinthose /deep/ is being deprecated ::ng-deep is here to stay :-)

Comment: @alexKhymenko OK.  I heard wrong from someone else then.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @alexKhymenko looks like xinthose is right, see:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 10):

For me, I needed to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` for my `styleURLs` to take effect:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testing.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am not sure why this is necessary.  It is needed in Angular 8 at least, but not in Angular 9 thankfully.

Comment: It's needed to remove component encapsulation that you have trouble penetrating, see:  
  
*Doesn't provide any sort of CSS style encapsulation, meaning that all the styles provided via Component#styles or Component#styleUrls are applicable to any HTML element of the application regardless of their host Component.*

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure it would help you or not but for me the issue was because i was using styles[] in my component because of which it was not able to read .scss file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myse-draft-order',
  styleUrls: ['./something.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './something.html',
  styles: [], // needs to be removed.
})
```