# Angular 6 not applying scss styles

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a component page and corresponding style sheet, however the classes in the component.scss dosen't apply to the page. There are no errors, I am still wondering why?

This is my product-detailpage.component.html

```
<div>
  <h1>Product Detail Page</h1>
</div>
```

This is the .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {ProductdetailService} from '../productdetail.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-detailpage',
  templateUrl: './product-detailpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detailpage.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailpageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private productData: ProductdetailService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is the .scss file

```
body{color:Red !important}
app-product-detailpage{
        h1{color:red !important}
}
```

However one thing I noticed was if I make changes to the global styles.css it works fine. just to check I changed the body color to green and it works.

My angular app is configured to work with scss. what could be the reason? can some one suggest?

Comment: I had a similar issue, and resolved using "encapsulation.none".
I was rendering the component programatically using the rootViewRef, so it didn't have its own shadow dom.

Comment: This is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218064/589227

Comment: Please read this article, there are many solition on there (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Answer (score 10):

Your SCSS won't work for your HTML file *product-detailpage.component.html*.

The reason is Angular uses [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) for components. That means the tags `<body>` and `<app-product-detailpage>` are nowhere to be found in your component.

Comment: Nope, it is incorrect By default  Angular *emulates style encapsulation*, it uses shadow DOM when you set view encapsulation to native `ViewEncapsulation.Native`

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 8):

As per the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope), The style specified in the component can only be applied to its template, which excludes the component.

This is the reason why your styles are not working on the component from component's style.scss but are working fine from global style sheet.

One way of doing it is to use `:host` pseudo selector as per [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) which allows to add styles on the container in which component is placed.

The documentation says -

`The :host selector is the only way to target the host element. You can't reach the host element from inside the component with other selectors because it's not part of the component's own template. The host element is in a parent component's template.`

Answer (score 8):

Because default css encapsulation in `Angular` is **`Emulated`**`(ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`) so Angular will render out like below:

```
input[_ngcontent-c0] {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

So if you want set style to the currently `component`, you can use **`Native`** option.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
```

It will render like as:

```
input {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

---

But finally I suggest you use **global** scss file to define style of `<web component>`.

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.Native was deprecated use ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom instead. 
https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation