# The style imported from a SCSS file in a NPM package isn't applied to my angular component

Tags: angular, sass, encapsulation

I'm new to Angular.

We have, in our company, a package containing the SCSS shared by several projects. Each component has its own SCSS set of files (pretty much the same as bootstrap-SASS does).
My angular project uses this package installed via npm.

If I import the component's SCSS I need in the styles.scss of my angular project the CSS is applied correctly. This is not what I want.
I want that the SCSS I need is loaded **only** from the angular component requiring it.

*> front/src/styles.scss*

```
    @import "~@company/style/scss/numerictextbox";
```

If I do the same import in in my angular component's SCSS file, the CSS is not applied.

*> front/src/app/item/item.component.scss*

```
    @import "~@company/style/scss/numerictextbox";
```

I can see my CSS in the `<style>` added in `<header>` but for some reason it is not applied.

I'm still trying to learn the ropes of Angular. Am I missing a big thing?

Here's my component:

*> front/src/app/item/item.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss'],
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() group: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: can you show how does your component look and has styleUrls.

Comment: are the css classes applied only to elements within that component or also in child components?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51034638/9386929

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 not applying scss styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032932/angular-6-not-applying-scss-styles)

Comment: I tried adding the property "encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.Native", it didn't make a difference.